# How do I control user input with specific criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to ask the user to input his/her name and the naming criteria is that the name should only consist of letters(upper case or lower case) and have a length of at least two. If the name entered by the user violates the naming criteria, a message "Not valid name" would be displayed and needs to re-input his/her name until he/she inputs a valid name.

Im not a computer science major and have asked some of my friends. They said I should use an array and ASCII? I don't know where to start. Please help.

Comment: This is quite a broad question - how much Python do you know? Are you looking for an entire script, or something more specific? What does your code look like currently?

Comment: This is my first course in coding so basically I know nothing :(. An entire script would be great! I'm starting from scratch right now.

Comment: An entire script is unlikely to help you learn much. Go through your course notes and look for things about `input()`, `for` loops, `break`, `print()`, and functions to work on strings. Then think about how you would do this task with on paper before trying to do it with Python

Comment: Also ignore your friends that mentioned arrays and ASCII